# How to design a package that can potentially take any data source and convert it into an extensible, read-only configuration object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, application-design

I have a Java package which purpose is to receive configuration parameters from an external config file (XML, JSON, CSV, etc.), convert them into a POJO and return it in a form of an immutable, extensible object to the caller. Caller may only read parameters, but not modify them. If loading, parsing or conversion fail, the package must return a default configuration object with basic number of settings and predefined values. In the future the number of settings might increase and there might be another data source.

[image]

Basically, it's a black box with input and output. Input can be any data source, with basic settings, that can potentially increase. Output is a Java object, which contains all settings (that, again, can potentially increase). And it must be read-only. First, I thought about writing an interface with getters for basic settings, which can be extended if the settings list expands? Something like

```
interface Config { ... }

abstract class BasicConfig implements Config {...}

class ExtendedConfig extends BasicConfig {...}
```

Then I thought that maybe parsing XML into a HashMap will solve the problem should the settings list increase in the future. In this case I can make `HashMap<String, Object>` and read anything from it without knowing how many settings it contains.

What would be the best design solution here?

Comment: Why would you want to use csv files for configuration? Would you have multiple lines for the same entry? Also why is `BasicConfig` abstract? You'd probably want to create an instance of that class if there are not additional settings, wouldn't you? And do you need typesafe settings, compile-time checks for existing getters etc. too? Or would it be ok to just do calls like `String c = get("someKey")`  or maybe `Boolean b = getBoolean("some_int_key")` (the latter also being meant to show a potential pitfall)?

Comment: Also, did you have a look at Java's properties system or Spring's configuration already? You could base your design on that and add immutablity on top by overriding any setters and throwing exceptions.

Comment: I was wondering if I can make the design somewhat extensible and easily modifiable if a) data source will change and b) if the list of configuration will expand. That is the client will always have `Config` implementation on its side and get any of the current settings, and we won't need to rewrite client code, changing `Config` to something like `ExtConfig`, and so on. Basically, its always `Config c = ConfigManager.getConfig(); c.getSetting(...);` And the list of available get methods just expands. 
I will check Java and Spring solution, thank you